# how to copy values from one sheet where the values are starting from a specific row

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy values from sheet named "Price Schedule" where the values which I want to start copying from "Row 10" and ONLY "Column D" and "Column F" should be copied. And paste it into another sheet named "Sheet1". It should start pasting values from "row 25" and paste under "Column H" and "Column I".

I want to put a condition statement where I want to copy only the rows which have the value grater than "zero" in "Column D" in sheet "Price Schedule" and paste it in "sheet1" under Column"H" and Column "I" starting from "row 25".

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

a = Worksheets("PRICE SCHEDULE").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For I = 2 To a
    If Worksheets("PRICE SCHEDULE").Cells(I, 4).Value = ">0" Then
        Worksheets("PRICE SCHEDULE").Rows(I).Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

        b = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        Worksheets("PRICE SCHEDULE").Activate
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

I tried doing this and passed a msgbox to see the results but it shows no results of the copied data.

Please see the images for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a filter for this task, like so:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rDest As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Worksheets("Price Schedule")
    Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rDest = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    If rDest.Row < 25 Then Set rDest = wsDest.Range("H25")

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With wsData.Range("D9:F" & wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
        If .Row < 9 Then GoTo CleanExit     'No data
        .AutoFilter 1, ">0", xlFilterValues 'Filter on column D for values >0
        Intersect(.Worksheet.Range("D:D,F:F"), .Offset(1)).Copy 'Copy filtered values in columns D and F only
        rDest.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues    'Paste values only to destination
        .AutoFilter 'Clear filter
    End With

CleanExit:
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, b As Long

With Worksheets("PRICE SCHEDULE")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 10 To LastRow ' loop from row 10 and forward
        If .Range("D" & i).Value >= 0 Then
            ' first get the next empty row to paste
            b = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

            ' copy column "D" to column "H"
            .Range("D" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & b)
            ' copy column "F" to column "I"
            .Range("F" & i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & b)
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not work. It does not do anything. Its not showing any error but the values are not getting pasted nor getting copied.